# Wordpress - Alter the form action url in wp-includes/comments-template.php

Tags: php, wordpress, https, woocommerce, comments

I am currently working on a website that is non ssl for the non eCommerce sections, but uses ssl for the woocommerce portion. I am attempting to redirect reviews of products to a thank you page, which I was able to get working just fine on staging. When moving to the live environment, The comment form is calling the post url as the following: " Where my client's website is using nonhttps urls everywhere except the woocommerce urls. So this is making it call the url as https://website.com/wp-comments-post.php, where it is white screen of deathing. I modified the core file for a moment to test the theory and it worked, I am just unable to find anything that will let me modified the url to change the https to http. I looked into comment_form(), but it doesn't appear to offer a hook or filter for this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you want to have save and a unsafe pages. Why don't you use https on you whole site instead of only the shop?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't my site, and I completely agree. That is what I am pushing, but I got to do what I was paid for first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree it doesn't make sense to not have https on some pages, especially form input. 
But doing a redirect for that form url in the .htaccess would be the way to go.

Comment: I ended up just securing the entire site after multiple convos with the client , but after researching this further. Your method seemed to be the most correct method of doing something not recommended. Thanks again!